# Problems about linked list

Tags: c, algorithm

This is a function about deleting a Node of one linked list,and next is the code.

```
//delete List
int deleteList(PNODE pHead,int pos)
{
    int i=0;
    PNODE p=pHead->pNext;
    //locate the position
    while(p!=NULL && i<pos-1)
    {
        p=p->pNext;
        i++;
    }
    if(i>pos-1 || p==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    PNODE q=p->pNext;
    p->pNext=q->pNext;
    free(q);
    return 1;
}
```

I do not know if there is actual use about the codes below:

```
if(i>pos-1 || p==NULL)
{
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah its is important because if there is no such node then it will reach where i=pos

Comment: whitout this, the codes also run.what does it used for?

Comment: your code should crash without this if you place a pos that's higher than the total number of nodes - 1, because it will try to free a null pointer. also,

Comment: Thank you,i know now.If pos<0,then i>pos.So this can judge if pos<0,because pos<0 makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the condition determining if you attempt to splice by dropping the check on `i`.  Your algorithm will already have correctly placed the `p` pointer on the node immediately before the node you want to splice.  You only want to take action if both `p` is not null *and* there exists a node after it to splice out.

```
if (p==NULL || p->pNext==NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    PNODE q=p->pNext;
    p->pNext=q->pNext;
    free(q);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation for the code, block by block.

1.

```
int i=0;
PNODE p=pHead->pNext;
```

This sets up the variables.  I is for index to keep track of our position in the linked list, p is to keep track of our node in the linked list.

2.

```
while(p!=NULL && i<pos-1)
{
    p=p->pNext;
    i++;
}
```

This iterates over the list until it either gets to the end (meaning that the position passed in was out of range of the list) or it reaches the position of the node we want to remove (minus 1).  At this point, i is going to be pos - 1 (the position of the element we want to remove - 1), and p is going to be the element before the node we want to remove.

3.

```
if(i>pos-1 || p==NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
```

This code checks to see if we actually found the position in the list we were looking for--if we ran out of list items before we got to `pos`, then we shouldn't do anything.  Essentially, if step 2 got to the end of the list without reaching `pos-1`, then we don't want to try to remove anything because we're out of the end of the list.

4.

```
PNODE q=p->pNext;
p->pNext=q->pNext;
free(q);
return 1;
```

This is the bit of code that actually removes things from the list.  Right now, p is the node BEFORE the one we want to remove (we set p to this in step 2).  So, we get the node we want to remove and put it in `q` with `PNODE q=p->pNext;`

Before we can remove q though, we have to put our linked list back together, so we have to set p's next node to q's next node with `p->pNext=q->pNext;`.  Basically, if we have a linked list `o->p->q->r`, we just changed it to `o->p->r`.  Once we have that set, we're ready to remove q and return success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sanity checking on the parameters. Half of this is checking whether a negative number has been passed in, and the other half is checking that you haven't read past the end of the list.

If you wanted to be totally safe you should check that pHead is not null before you dereference it's members.